# Calculate column difference with NULLs in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I've tried asking this question in the official Tableau-forum with no success.

I am currently trying to calculate the difference between two columns, using the same dimension and measure. Basically what I want to do is having the Excel-equivalent of just a simple "difference between two columns" calculation.

I found (sort of) an answer using a previously asked question, with a lot of suggested solutions attached to it [in this post](https://community.tableau.com/thread/232077). Using the results from there I came up with this:

[image]

The resulting table looks like:

[image]

Everything here looks fine where there is a number/value present for the measure `[Market Val Pct Adjusted]` in both **PF** and **PF Benchmark**.

However, when there is a NULL value (or missing value) in `[Market Val Pct Adjusted]` in the PF portfolio (**Portfolio Name** dimension), i.e. when there is only a valid value in the **PF Benchmark** dimension - instead of showing

```
(0.0 - 0.09) = -0.09
```

for the **Subsector D** in the **Total**-column, *it shows positive 0.09*... I suppose this is due to the fact that in the `IF`-clause, since there is no data available for **PF**, it'll result in a `False` and hence return `SUM([Market Val Pct Adjusted])` for **PF Benchmark**. Changing this to negative only results in unwanted negative values elsewhere.

So far, I have already tried to use `zn()` functionality for the `[Market Val Pct Adjusted]` field, as well as trying to replace all NULLs with zeros within the table using `zn(lookup(sum([[Market Val Pct Adjusted]]), 0))` with no good results.

Anyone out there having a clue on how to fix this, rather annoying, issue?

Unfortunately, I can't attach any example atm, as the data is sensitive and non-public. The only re-usable data available is the one uploaded in the previous-mentioned example link above.

Thanks,

/N

---

Using suggestions mentioned in comment section in the `IF`-clause as so:

[image]

Yields no change in the table output... And no zeros in stead of NULLs either.

Answer (score 1):

I think `IFNULL([Market Val Pct Adjusted],0)` should work

Comment: Thanks for answering @akshay - however, it doesn't seem to bite. Have tried to both apply the IFNULL() on the measure [Market Val Pct Adjusted] as well as within the earlier mentioned IF clause.

Comment: Had any time to revisit the problem @akshay? Thanks

Comment: Yeah I just revisited. Will post if I come up with some solution. @gussilago

Comment: Nothing new? I haven't found an easy soultion myself as of yet @akshay

Comment: How about creating a separate calculated field using `IFNULL` and the use that calculated field for your calculation?

Comment: Hi again @akshay
Thing is, the field called [Market Val Pct Adjusted] is already defined within a IFNULL - and still no results...